# Space below the box in mdframed package doesn't appear

Tags: spacing, boxes, mdframed

I am using the mdframed package along with the options `skipabove` and `skipbelow` and although the vertical space above the box is appearing, as it should, the space below does't appear! What am I doing wrong and it doesn't appear? How should I fix it?

As an extra question why when I use the `parskip` package instead of adding vertical space above and below it does the exact opposite?

[image]

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mdframed}

\begin{document}

Text above

\begin{mdframed}[skipabove=2cm, skipbelow=2cm]

Text in box

\end{mdframed}

Text below

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to try with `tcolorbox`, it seems that `before skip` and `after skip` work as expected.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}

Text above

\begin{tcolorbox}[before skip=2cm, after skip=2cm]

Text in box

\end{tcolorbox}

Text below

\end{document}
```

[image]

*Update*: `more minimalistic`

```
If `more minimalistic` means a box like the one shown in question, it's not too difficult to get a similar one with `tcolorbox`

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\newtcolorbox{minimal}{%
    sharp corners, colback=white, colframe=black, notitle,
    before skip=2cm, after skip=2cm}

\begin{document}

Text above

\begin{minimal}

Text in box

\end{minimal}

Text below

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Damn, you were quicker with `tcolorbox` (;-)). Actually, I never got `mdframed` to work as I intended. (+1)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer i think it is a known problem in mdframed

Comment: @daleif: I see -- thanks for information.

Comment: Thanks. I use tcolorbox sometimes but mdframed seemed more minimalistic in this case. If this is a known issue then I will use the tcolorbox again.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Don't worry, next time you will the faster. As usual. ;-)

Comment: @Ignasi: I worry. I am terribly upset ;-)

Comment: @Adam I hope my updated answer looks `more minimalistic`.

Comment: Yes indeed it is very good.